# sql create table ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a table and I am getting the error `invalid datatype`. I have tried to change of the variables, but the error remains. Can someone help me?

**Code:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE DETALLEFACTURA (
    NUMERO_FACTURA_DETALLE NUMBER(15),
    NUMERO_DETALLE_FACTURA VARCHAR(20),
    CODIGO_ARTICULO VARCHAR(20),
    CANTIDAD NUMBER(6),
    PORCENTAJE_GANANCIA NUMBER(10),
    PRECIO NUMBER(8),
    CONSTRAINT DETALLE_PK PRIMARY KEY(NUMERO_FACTURA_DETALLE,NUMERO_DETALLE_FACTURA), 

    CONSTRAINT (NUMERO_FACTURA_DETALLE_FK) FOREIGN KEY(NUMERO_FACTURA_DETALLE) REFERENCES FACTURA(NUMERO_FACTURA) on delete cascade,
    CONSTRAINT (NUMERO_DETALLE_FACTURA_FK) FOREIGN KEY(NUMERO_DETALLE_FACTURA) REFERENCES ARTICULO(CODIGO_ARTICULO) on delete cascade
);
```

**Error**

```
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming from the parentheses you have around the constraint names; this gets the same error:

```
create table FACTURA(NUMERO_FACTURA NUMBER(15) primary key);
create table ARTICULO(CODIGO_ARTICULO VARCHAR(20) primary key);

CREATE TABLE DETALLEFACTURA(
NUMERO_FACTURA_DETALLE NUMBER(15),
NUMERO_DETALLE_FACTURA VARCHAR(20),
CODIGO_ARTICULO VARCHAR(20),
CANTIDAD NUMBER(6),
PORCENTAJE_GANANCIA NUMBER(10),
PRECIO NUMBER(8),
CONSTRAINT DETALLE_PK PRIMARY KEY(NUMERO_FACTURA_DETALLE,NUMERO_DETALLE_FACTURA), 
CONSTRAINT (NUMERO_FACTURA_DETALLE_FK) FOREIGN KEY(NUMERO_FACTURA_DETALLE) REFERENCES FACTURA(NUMERO_FACTURA) on delete cascade,
CONSTRAINT (NUMERO_DETALLE_FACTURA_FK) FOREIGN KEY(NUMERO_DETALLE_FACTURA) REFERENCES ARTICULO(CODIGO_ARTICULO) on delete cascade
);
```

ORA-00902: invalid datatype

This does not:

```
CREATE TABLE DETALLEFACTURA(
NUMERO_FACTURA_DETALLE NUMBER(15),
NUMERO_DETALLE_FACTURA VARCHAR(20),
CODIGO_ARTICULO VARCHAR(20),
CANTIDAD NUMBER(6),
PORCENTAJE_GANANCIA NUMBER(10),
PRECIO NUMBER(8),
CONSTRAINT DETALLE_PK PRIMARY KEY(NUMERO_FACTURA_DETALLE,NUMERO_DETALLE_FACTURA), 
CONSTRAINT NUMERO_FACTURA_DETALLE_FK FOREIGN KEY(NUMERO_FACTURA_DETALLE) REFERENCES FACTURA(NUMERO_FACTURA) on delete cascade,
CONSTRAINT NUMERO_DETALLE_FACTURA_FK FOREIGN KEY(NUMERO_DETALLE_FACTURA) REFERENCES ARTICULO(CODIGO_ARTICULO) on delete cascade
);

Table DETALLEFACTURA created.
```

The only difference is the removal of the parentheses on the last two constraints.

---

Incidentally, Oracle [recommends using `varchar2` instead of `varchar`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#sthref73); it won't cause errors but it will cause confusion, and it's better to follow their recommendations when you can. They've been saying it will be redefined for as long as I can remember, but who knows, it may happen one day...

Comment: Regarding your last comment ("it may happen one day...") - I can't wait! The main reason for redefining VARCHAR, as far as I understand, has to do with Oracle adhering to the SQL Standard - in particular, allowing for empty strings as being different from `NULL`. (Empty strings and `NULL` are the same thing in Oracle, contrary to the SQL Standard and to logic.)

Comment: @mathguy Nothing like embarrassing yourself by assertively providing a wrong answer. I have deleted my previous answer per your suggestion.

Comment: @BrianLeach - Nothing embarrassing about that - I give wrong answers all the time, and I am comfortable knowing I was trying to help the OP and (usually) there was a reason I thought the answer was correct, even when it wasn't. I have many downvoted answers of my own, which is fine; I delete them (with or without the downvotes) when I realize they are wrong, or they don't apply to the OP. We all do what we can to keep the site as useful as possible. (Or, I shouldn't say we **all**, since that isn't true; at least many of us!) Thank you for helping with that!